# Google analytics - using events as convertion goals

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have some google analytics events on my site, and have now started using Google Adwords. Adwords normally uses goals not events to show conversion rates, but can I somehow use my events instead to see conversions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to make two simple steps to use Google Analytics events as conversions in AdWords :

1. Create Goal in analytics for your events. You need to use custom
   goal and event as Goal Type. Check the [Google Analytics guide.](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032415?hl=en)
2. Import your goals to AdWords. That's pretty easy process and AdWords
   has [a manual for this.](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2375435?hl=en) You'll just need your AdWords and
   Analytics accounts to be linked.

Comment: Thanks, ill give it a try.